# .Xresources file ignored on OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 with GNOME

Tags: linux, xorg, gnome, opensuse, xterm

I have written an `.Xresources` file with `xterm` settings, and it is not loaded when user logs in: the `xterm` has the ugly default settings when launched. This happens on a VirtualBox VM running OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 with Gnome and multimedia patterns installed. Except for VirtualBox Guest Additions, `kernel-devel` and `git`, it is a fresh install "as shipped".

The settings are correctly loaded after I run

```
xrdb -merge .Xresource
```

and relaunch `xterm`

Adding the above command to `.xinitrc` file, created based on template from OpenSUSE, has no effect. I've tried to add `xclock &` to `.xinitrc`, but no clock appears on login. So I guess `.xinitrc` is ignored.

The bizarre detail is that I run the said VM on another OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 physical machine, with exactly same OS installation, and there my `.Xresources` file is loaded! In fact, the VM was intentionally created as similar to the PM as possible for experimenting and testing.

The PM has NVIDIA card, and CUDA packages are installed. I have run the same Ansible playbook against the VM that I used to configure PM to see if CUDA packages make any difference, but no - `.Xresources` still ignored.

So, what am I missing here? How to get Xterm configured persistently? I'd be grateful if someone could point me to the relevant documentation, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it next morning after posting on Superuser - as usual :).

Gnome uses Wayland by default, which ignores the X11 dot files. But there is a notable exception - with NVIDIA drivers, the default is X11-based Gnome "due to instability", according to this Debian page:

https://wiki.debian.org/Wayland#GNOME

To switch to X11-Gnome, click the cogwheel icon before entering password when logging in, and select "Gnome on Xorg". If you've configured automatic login, you won't see any, of course.

To test which kind of session you are running,

```
~> echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```